# Jruby - Foreman Gem not running

Tags: java, jruby

I am running a JRUBY app. And stumbled accross a great gem called Foreman:
https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

However I found out - that the JVM does not support forking:

```
 foreman startNotImplementedError: fork is not available on this platform
              fork at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1657
      fork_with_io at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/process.rb:32
       run_process at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/process.rb:44
               run at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/process.rb:19
  with_environment at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/process.rb:64
               run at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/process.rb:18
             chdir at org/jruby/RubyDir.java:466
               run at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/process.rb:17
             spawn at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/procfile_entry.rb:17
               map at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2336
             spawn at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/procfile_entry.rb:15
   spawn_processes at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/engine.rb:63
              each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1609
   spawn_processes at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/engine.rb:61
             start at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/engine.rb:45
             start at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/lib/foreman/cli.rb:28
          __send__ at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1772
              send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1972
               run at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:21
       invoke_task at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118
          dispatch at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263
             start at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389
            (root) at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/gems/foreman-0.36.1/bin/foreman:7
              load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:996
            (root) at /home/charlie/.rvm/gems/jruby-head/bin/foreman:19
```

This was a shame, as I loved the idea of running Foreman. Does anyone know a work around for the above issue, or an alternative that will run inside a JRUBY environment

Comment: Using the Spoon gem might be the way to go if you feel like patching foreman.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the awesome work of the creators of this gem, this is now available in Jruby

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

Is running fine in Jruby 1.6.6

Answer (score 0):

Another few options are a RVM wrapper and Guard::Process as outlined here: http://www.without-brains.net/blog/2011/09/21/using-foreman-to-run-jruby-with-rvm-and-mri/

Comment: This link is dead, does anyone have any idea what it said?